# representation of a linear bounded operator

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

Let $T\in B(H)$ and $H=H_1\oplus H_2$, then $T$ can be expressed by the following matrix:

\begin{pmatrix}A & B\\C & D\end{pmatrix}
, where $A\in B(H_1), B\in B(H_2,H_1), C\in B(H_1,H_2),D\in B(H_2)$.

How to represent the operator $T|_{H_1}$ which is restricted to the closed subspace $H_1$ in terms of the matrix? $H_1$ may not be an invariant subspcae of $T$.

Comment: Which is the (block) matrix for the projection from $H=H_1\oplus H_2$ to $H_1$? (For instance for $H_1=H_2=\Bbb R$)? Then just multiply the matrices...

Comment: You mean if  we let $P$ be the orthogonal projection from $H$ to $H_1$ and $Z$ be the above matrix, then $T_{H_1}=TP$, but the domain of $T|_{H_1}$ is $H_1$ ,rather than $H$.

Comment: Let $U:H_1\to H_1\oplus H_2$ act by $Ux=x.$ Then $T\mid_{H_1}=TU.$

Comment: Do you mean $T |_{H_1}x =Ax \oplus Bx$, $x \in H_1$?